# Drarry fan fiction where Draco lives in New York and works at a tattoo shop

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I am looking for a really long Drarry fan fiction where Draco lives in New York and works at a tattoo shop as well as with at risk youth.  He is 'cursed' to see Harry in his dreams.  The story is centred around Draco.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably "[The Man Who Lived](http://dragontamerdrarry.tumblr.com/post/169924287564/the-man-who-lived)" by sebastianL.

> Draco works in a tattoo shop, and also volunteers as a mentor for troubled kids, juvenile delinquents in New York. And you can see how much he’s moulded himself into his new life and how much it’s all a part of him now. He ends up seeing Harry in his dreams almost 12 years later, and despite their interactions going horribly at first, they slowly start to understand each other as they try to figure out why this is happening. It really is beautiful, the sheer amount Draco cares for his ‘boys’ and their futures, its so visceral and deep. And it’s such a contrast, seeing Dracos current adult personality set against his old self with all of the rough edges that Harry and the flashbacks to Dracos past brings back to him.

Found by searching for *fanfic draco "new york" "tattoo shop"*